# Show that $\ln(1+x)=\ln x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{3x^3}-\frac{1}{4x^4}+\cdots$ when $x>1$

Tags: logarithms

> If $x>1$ show that $\ln(1+x)=\ln x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{3x^3}-\frac{1}{4x^4}+\cdots$

I know from binomial expansion that $(1+x)$ will produce a divergent series in the form of $1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$ but I don't know how to apply that in this situation.

Do I just need to integrate $\ln(1-x+x^2+\cdots$)? If so, why integrate? What role does integration have here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Expand $\ln(1+x)-\ln(x)=\ln(1+u)$ into a power series in $u=1/x$ with $|u|\lt1$.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Where does $\ln x$ come from? Isn't $\frac{1}{x}$ the first term?

Comment: ?? $\ln x$ "comes from" the RHS of the identity you want to prove.

Comment: I understand now - since you minus $\ln x$ on the LHS, you need to balance it out on the right.

Comment: Yes-this is one way to say it.

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\ln(1+x)-\ln x\\
&=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align}
$$

By differenting w.r.t. $x$ and writing as sum of infinite GP
$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=\frac{1}{1+\frac1x}\cdot\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac1x+\frac{1}{x^2}-\cdots\right)\\
f'(x)&=-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^4}+\cdots\\
\end{align}$$
By integrating
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\cdots\\
\ln(1+x)-\ln x&=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\cdots\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\ln(1+x)=\ln x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\cdots$$